# Android Spinner: Personalizar color de DropDown

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Necesito personalizar el color de fondo de un DropDown, hasta el momento llegue a realizar esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en lo posible trataria de darle bordes redondeados y que tenga el mismo color que tienen los TextViews de fondo (Como ven el fondo es blanco), para llegar a realizar eso, este es mi codigo:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#bdfbea"
android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa"
android:padding="20dp"
android:textColor="#00887b"
android:textSize="24sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:maxLines="1"/>
```

//

```
    String[] idiomas = {"ESPAÑOL", "ENGLISH", "PORTUGUES"};
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.sp_idioma);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_textview, idiomas);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropview);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

PD: ya probe con `android:popupBackground="COLOR"` y no a funcinado, tambien probe varias soluciones de la web, y ninguna da con la respuesta

//-------------------------------------------------AGREGADO

Uso un Contraint Layout para orientar los componentes, mi componenete spinner esta configurado de la siguiente manera

```
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_idioma"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_personalizado"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_idioma" />
```

El Background es el siguiente:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#bdfbea" />

                <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#00887b" />

                <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="15dp" android:top="1dp" />

                <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:gravity="center|right"
                android:src="@drawable/img_flecha_spinner"
                />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Comment: @user8322213 quizas sabes cual es mi error, confio en vos :D

Answer (score 1):

Para esto debes usar tu Adapter personalizado y dentro del método `getView(`) puedes sobre escribir los colores del texto y del fondo:

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
        TextView txv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        txv.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
        //Color Fondo.
        txv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDFCEB"));
        //Color Texto.
        txv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2D9989")); 
        txv.setText(values.get(pos));

        return view;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Este sería el código del Adapter para que lo tengas como referencia:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jorgesys
 */
class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    List<String> values;
    Context context;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<String> values )
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return values.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return values.get(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0)
    {
        return arg0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
        TextView txv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        txv.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
        //Color Fondo.
        txv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDFCEB"));
        //Color Texto.
        txv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2D9989")); 
        txv.setText(values.get(pos));

        return view;
    }

}
```

Para usar este Adapter, simplemente configuralo a tu Spinner:

```
   spinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listadeDatos));
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, cree mi propio adapter con el codigo que me pasaste y lo hice funcionar, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema, el fondo blanco, se sigue viendo tal cual.

Comment: Ok ese Espanol es creator por un padding, agrega por favor el layout. @LcsGrz

Comment: Ahi añadi mas info sobre mi proyecto, espero que sea de ayuda. Estoy aprendiendo del mundo de android y hay cosas que se me complican por la falta de practica. Gracias por ser buen compañero :D